How is transfinite ordinal arithmetic done?
Let $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ be two transfinite ordinals such that $\alpha_1 \neq \alpha_2$, and neither $\alpha_1$ or $\alpha_2$ are limit ordinals.
How is $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2$ defined? From intuition I'd assume that
$$
\lambda = \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 = (\alpha_1 \cup\alpha_2),
$$
which would make sense for $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = \omega$ ($\omega$ defined as $\{n|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$) being $\omega2$. However, I'm not entirely sure
I'm thinking through this correctly. Is this how addition is defined?

The order type of $\alpha +\beta$ is always the order of the disjoint union with $\alpha$ preceding $\beta$, whether the ordinals are finite, transfinite, limit ordinals, or not limit ordinals. Note that ordinal addition is generally not commutative.

$\omega 2=\omega+\omega$ is different from $\omega \cup \omega = \omega$.

@ArturoMagidin You have been using this site for many years. Probably you should know. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information.
